# Не могу правильно "считать" нажатие кнопки

Tags: linux, c, ввод

Столкнулся с такой проблемой. Не получается  "принять" сигнал от кнопке на аппарате.

Мне достался аппарат на котором етсь одна программируемая кнопка. 
Чтобы её считать надо вызвать команду `cat /dev/input/event1` Я как понял, команда считывает что складывается в файл `event1` и выводит это.

Мне надо чтоб я мог с ней работать. При нажатии начнётся запуск функции программы.

При запуске `cat dev/input/event1`, я получал такой результат. (как по мне весьма бестолковый )

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я воспользовался библиотекой ncurses. 
Но она выводит сообщения о нажатии клавиатуры ))) (аппарат присоединен через ком порт к компу "в аппарате своего монитора нету")

```
#include <ncurses.h>
#include "conio.h"
 ...
int z = getch();
printf("Key %c code %d\n", z, z);
...
```

Код выводит нажатие клавиатуры,НО не выводит нажатие свободно программируемой кнопки на аппарате.

Воспользовался утилитой [evtest](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingTouchpadDetection/evtest) **вот что надо :3**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Я подумал что можно взять `code` и сделать на него "реакцию".

Я надёргал из утилиты [evtest](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingTouchpadDetection/evtest) такого кода, но у меня он почему-то выводит какую то дрянь.

А хотелось бы чтоб выводил "нажатие" кнопки.

```
#include <linux/version.h>
#include <linux/input.h>

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
//---
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <getopt.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define BITS_PER_LONG (sizeof(long) * 8)
#define NBITS(x) ((((x)-1)/BITS_PER_LONG)+1)
#define OFF(x) ((x)%BITS_PER_LONG)
#define BIT(x) (1UL<<OFF(x))
#define LONG(x) ((x)/BITS_PER_LONG)
#define test_bit(bit, array)    ((array[LONG(bit)] >> OFF(bit))&1)

#define DEV_INPUT_EVENT "/dev/input"
#define EVENT_DEV_NAME "event"

#ifndef EV_SYN
#define EV_SYN 0
#endif
#ifndef SYN_MAX
#define SYN_MAX 3
#define SYN_CNT (SYN_MAX +1)
#endif
#ifndef SYN_MT_REPORT
#define SYN_MT_REPORT 2
#endif
#ifndef SYN_DROPPED
#define SYN_DROPPED 3
#endif

#define NAME_ELEMENT(element) [element] = #element

static const int maxval[EV_MAX + 1] = {
    [0 ... EV_MAX] = -1,
    [EV_SYN] = SYN_MAX,
    [EV_KEY] = KEY_MAX,
    [EV_REL] = REL_MAX,
    [EV_ABS] = ABS_MAX,
    [EV_MSC] = MSC_MAX,
    [EV_SW] = SW_MAX,
    [EV_LED] = LED_MAX,
    [EV_SND] = SND_MAX,
    [EV_REP] = REP_MAX,
    [EV_FF] = FF_MAX,
    [EV_FF_STATUS] = FF_STATUS_MAX,
};

int main() {
    printf("losst.ru\n");
    printf("Koren: %f\n", sqrt(9));

    char *filename;
    int fd;

    asprintf(&filename, "%s/%s%d", DEV_INPUT_EVENT, EVENT_DEV_NAME,1);

    if(!filename)
        return EXIT_FAILURE;

    printf("%s\n", filename);
    int fdi = 1;
    printf("%s%s%d.\n", DEV_INPUT_EVENT, EVENT_DEV_NAME,fdi);
    printf("TYT\n");

    struct input_event ev[64];
    int i; int rd;
    fd_set rdfs;

    FD_ZERO(&rdfs);
    FD_SET(fd, &rdfs);

    while(1){

        printf("1\n");

        printf("1.1\n");

        rd = read(fd, ev, sizeof(ev));

        printf("2\n");

        for (i=0;i<rd/sizeof(struct input_event);i++){
            unsigned int type, code;

            type=ev[i].type;
            type=ev[i].code;
            printf("3\n");
            printf("Event: time %ld.%06ld, ", ev[i].time.tv_sec, ev[i].time.tv_usec);
            if (type == EV_SYN){
                if(code == SYN_MT_REPORT)
                    printf("++++  ++++\n");
                else if(code == SYN_DROPPED)
                    printf(">>>>  >>>>\n");
                else
                    printf("-----  -----\n");
            } else {
                printf("type %d , code %d ", type, code);
                printf("4\n");
                if(type == EV_MSC && (code == MSC_RAW || code == MSC_SCAN))
                    printf("value %02x\n", ev[i].value);
                else
                    printf("value %d\n", ev[i].value);
            }   
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

вот вывод кода (((

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Вот не знаю как правильно получить результат от нажатия свободно программируемой кнопки, чтоб без множества функции.** Что то типо подключить один заголовочный файл и вызвать одну функцию.

<sub>Нажми на кнопку получишь результат :3</sub>

Comment: ты файл забыл открыть, поэтому `fd` не инициализирован... просто добавь `fd = open (filename, O_RDONLY);` в начало ... мораль басни такова: не забывай добавлять контроль ошибок ко всем системным вызовам (в частности `read ()`) и исправляй предупреждения компилятора... в остальном код по сути рабочий...

Comment: и да, ещё здесь описка: `type=ev[i].code;`

Comment: @Fat-Zer Да спасибо,  заработало как только внёс ваши правки. Оформляйте как ответ (если не оформите в течении двух дней то я оформлю).

Comment: пиши... нормальный ответ я написать не осилю...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Fat-Zer Дал ответ :3

> ты файл забыл открыть, поэтому `fd` не инициализирован... просто добавь
>   `fd = open (filename, O_RDONLY);` в начало ... мораль басни такова: не
>   забывай добавлять контроль ошибок ко всем системным вызовам (в
>   частности `read ()`) и исправляй предупреждения компилятора...
>   и да, ещё здесь описка: `type=ev[i].code;`

Вот исправленный код

```
#include <linux/version.h>
#include <linux/input.h>

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
//---
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <getopt.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define BITS_PER_LONG (sizeof(long) * 8)
#define NBITS(x) ((((x)-1)/BITS_PER_LONG)+1)
#define OFF(x) ((x)%BITS_PER_LONG)
#define BIT(x) (1UL<<OFF(x))
#define LONG(x) ((x)/BITS_PER_LONG)
#define test_bit(bit, array)    ((array[LONG(bit)] >> OFF(bit))&1)

#define DEV_INPUT_EVENT "/dev/input"
#define EVENT_DEV_NAME "event"

#ifndef EV_SYN
#define EV_SYN 0
#endif
#ifndef SYN_MAX
#define SYN_MAX 3
#define SYN_CNT (SYN_MAX +1)
#endif
#ifndef SYN_MT_REPORT
#define SYN_MT_REPORT 2
#endif
#ifndef SYN_DROPPED
#define SYN_DROPPED 3
#endif

#define NAME_ELEMENT(element) [element] = #element

static const int maxval[EV_MAX + 1] = {
    [0 ... EV_MAX] = -1,
    [EV_SYN] = SYN_MAX,
    [EV_KEY] = KEY_MAX,
    [EV_REL] = REL_MAX,
    [EV_ABS] = ABS_MAX,
    [EV_MSC] = MSC_MAX,
    [EV_SW] = SW_MAX,
    [EV_LED] = LED_MAX,
    [EV_SND] = SND_MAX,
    [EV_REP] = REP_MAX,
    [EV_FF] = FF_MAX,
    [EV_FF_STATUS] = FF_STATUS_MAX,
};

int main() {
    printf("losst.ru\n");
    printf("Koren: %f\n", sqrt(9));

    char *filename;
    int fd;

    asprintf(&filename, "%s/%s%d", DEV_INPUT_EVENT, EVENT_DEV_NAME,1);

    if(!filename)
        return EXIT_FAILURE;

    if((fd=open(filename, O_RDONLY)) < 0){
     perror("evtest");
      if(errno == EACCES && getuid() !=0)
        fprint(stderr, "You do not have access to %s. Try "
            "running as root instead.\n", filename);
     return 1;
    }

    printf("%s\n", filename);
    int fdi = 1;
    printf("%s%s%d.\n", DEV_INPUT_EVENT, EVENT_DEV_NAME,fdi);
    printf("TYT\n");

    struct input_event ev[64];
    int i; int rd;
    fd_set rdfs;

    FD_ZERO(&rdfs);
    FD_SET(fd, &rdfs);

    while(1){

        printf("1\n");

        printf("1.1\n");

        rd = read(fd, ev, sizeof(ev));

        printf("2\n");

        for (i=0;i<rd/sizeof(struct input_event);i++){
            unsigned int type, code;

            type=ev[i].type;
            code=ev[i].code;
            printf("3\n");
            printf("Event: time %ld.%06ld, ", ev[i].time.tv_sec, ev[i].time.tv_usec);
            if (type == EV_SYN){
                if(code == SYN_MT_REPORT)
                    printf("++++  ++++\n");
                else if(code == SYN_DROPPED)
                    printf(">>>>  >>>>\n");
                else
                    printf("-----  -----\n");
            } else {
                printf("type %d , code %d ", type, code);
                printf("4\n");
                if(type == EV_MSC && (code == MSC_RAW || code == MSC_SCAN))
                    printf("value %02x\n", ev[i].value);
                else
                    printf("value %d\n", ev[i].value);
            }   
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Вот вывод :

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]